# SignalR SqlDependency breaks when I make SqlCommand generic

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using SignalR to receive updates made to the database.  I tried to make my method for doing this generic as shown below, however, this breaks the SQL dependency as it does not fire when there is a change in the DB.  I have narrowed down the source of the problem to the SQL command which seems to stop it from working.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllMessages<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var messages = new List<T>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo]." + typeof(T).Name, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                var dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new T();
                    ConvertReaderToRelevantModel(reader, row);
                    messages.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

        return messages;
    }
```

If I change the SQL command to the snippet below it works as expected:

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [ID], 
            [Name], [Number], [DateLastUpdated] FROM [dbo].[HeartBeats]", connection))
```

What is stopping this from working and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`typef(T).Name` is not what you expect. put a breakpoint and take a look.

Comment: It is actually exactly what I expect.  I am using code first migrations so my model types have a matching table of the same name.

Comment: do you not have a namespace?

Comment: also, is it plural? in your example the table name is plural, your class name probably is not.

Comment: The names match and the command works the first time as it pulls the data back.  The problem is that it does not work again, the SqlDependency does not fire if there is a change in the DB